# Is it possible to pass a Cursor through IPC in Android?

Tags: android, cursor, ipc, aidl

I'm interesting if it is possible to pass a Cursor object through IPC and if it is possible how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the thread you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243978/375929

They say, implement CrossProcessCursor and wrap it around the cursor you've received from .query(); check out the example.

Comment: please consider accepting the answer, if it did the trick for you.